# Proof that the expression $a^2−b^2\neq 1$ for any pair of positive natural numbers

Tags: proof-verification, logic

Proof that for all positive natural numbers:  $$(a^2-b^2)\ $$

never equals to one.

To prove that I would use contradiction saying that,

$$(a^2-b^2)=1\ $$
$$(a-b)(a+b)=1\ $$

but that would mean that: 
$$(a-b)=1  \land (a+b)=1 $$
$$ \rightarrow a-b=1, a=1+b \land a+b=1,a=1+b$$
$$ a=a, 1+b=1-b  $$  that is only true when b=0, but 0 is not a natural number so it false.

I am not really sure if the proof can be expressed in this way and I would appreciate any help.

Comment: "0 is not a natural number" -- lies and slander!

Comment: Some definitions of "natural number" include zero, so the definition used must be made clearer (in this case, the proposition is only true for natural numbers excluding zero).

Comment: Yes, it meant to be for all positive natural numbers. I forgot to mention.

Comment: @Telaa The "positive" part is a little redundant when used with natural numbers since I've never seen a definition allowing for negative natural numbers. Zero is the only grey area. Might as well just say "positive integers" in this case, which is an unambiguous way of specifying the meaning in your question. And a good alternative phrasing for the case when you want to include zero as a possibility is "non-negative integers".

Comment: Thanks, I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Your proof is correct, modulo a small typo: you write $a+b = 1, a = 1 + b$ but this should of course be $a = 1 - b$ (which is also what you use in the next line, so clearly you meant that). As a small point of feedback: try to avoid unnecessary mathematical symbols and write it in words instead. So for example, replace "$\to$" by "and thus" or "so", and replace "$(a-b)=1 \land (a+b)=1$ by "$(a-b)=1$ and $(a+b)=1$" and so on.

Comment: Not relevant to your proof, but another appoach could be to notice that $b<a$, and write $a = b+k$ for some positive integer $k$. Then $$a^2 - b^2 = (b+k)^2 - b^2 = 2bk + k^2$$ which is at least $3$.

Answer (score 3):

Well, no. If $(a-b)(a+b)=1$, then either $a-b=a+b=1$ or $a-b=a+b=-1$.

Comment: In that case we'd have $b>a$ which directly shows $a^2 - b^2 <1$.

Comment: Correct. But $a, b > 0$ rules out $a + b = -1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is a very good one. Ideally you would mention that $a$ must be greater than $b$ and then your equations are correct.

Also, it would be better to talk about 'positive integers' so that everyone knows that you are excluding $0$.

Comment: I don't see why it should be mentioned that we must have $a > b$? Sure, if that is not the case then $a^2-b^2$ is never going to be positive. But the reasoning steps hold equally well when $a \leq b$, so it would seem like a superfluous remark in the proof.

Comment: You must rule out either $a+b=-1$ or $a-b=-1$. Whichever you prefer.

Comment: Ah, I see, you're right!

Answer (score 0):

An other approach. Let a and b be two positive integers.

If a² = b² + 1, then a² > b², and a > b

Now (b+1)² = b² + 2b + 1 = a² + 2b > a² and b + 1 > a

But there is no integer between b and b+1, a² - b² is never equal to 1